# How to correctly handle pixels in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, retina-display

How can I in a right way work with pixel dimensions in Interface Builder? E.g i have an image mockup where all dimensions and sizes in pixels : "this button has margin from the left - 30 pixels e.g. and this textfield is 100 pixels long and so on".So if I develop for Retina i need to set margin 60 pt or not? And in IB there are only Retina 3.5 and Retina 4 and there is no non-Retina. So what is a right way to handle retina and non retina screens in IB?How to correctly set dimensions for UI elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're working with logical points and not pixels at all. That's why you shouldn't worry about retina and non retina since iOS is going to translate logical points to pixels at runtime.

What do you mean when you say

> in IB there are only Retina 3.5 and Retina 4 and there is no
>   non-Retina

Comment: Ok so as i understood - if I set margin from left side for a button as 30 pt then it all will be ok in Retina and non-Retina?
And by this "in IB there are only Retina 3.5 and Retina 4 and there is no non-Retina" i mean than in IB Simulated metrics->Size i can see only: Retina 3.5,Retina 4, Freeform and None. But where is non-Retina?

Comment: Yes, you can set a 30pt margin and it will be ok in Retina and non-Retina. Regarding IB sizes, I never used those, I just checked and I also have only 3.5 retina and 4 retina but most likely this won't be a problem. Again, since 3.5 retina has 320x480 points in any case you can layout on that also UI for 3.5 non retina

Answer (score 1):

When designing UI in ios you need to have in mind that all measures are made in points, not pixels. So if you have mockup in size 640x960 you need to cut all elements in two versions, one is non retina (320x480) and need to be named as usual i.e test.png and retina version with size of (640x960) named test@2x.png. Notice that image name is same, only @2x is different, which actually indicates that image is retina iOS automatically will decide which image to show, whether test.png or test@2x.png.
About what measurements are used in interface builder, you can always do your calculations in non retina sizes, example if your button have 60px retina marigin you need to set value to 30.

Comment: "if your button have 60px retina marigin you need to set value to 30." -Ok but when i did so in Interface Builder the actual margin in Interface Builder is visibly much more than on the mockup... Or if I run it on real non Retina device all will be ok?